# Dumping a multiprocessing.Queue into a list

Tags: python, queue, multiprocessing

I wish to dump a `multiprocessing.Queue` into a list. For that task I've written the following function:

```
import Queue

def dump_queue(queue):
    """
    Empties all pending items in a queue and returns them in a list.
    """
    result = []

    # START DEBUG CODE
    initial_size = queue.qsize()
    print("Queue has %s items initially." % initial_size)
    # END DEBUG CODE

    while True:
        try:
            thing = queue.get(block=False)
            result.append(thing)
        except Queue.Empty:

            # START DEBUG CODE
            current_size = queue.qsize()
            total_size = current_size + len(result)
            print("Dumping complete:")
            if current_size == initial_size:
                print("No items were added to the queue.")
            else:
                print("%s items were added to the queue." % \
                      (total_size - initial_size))
            print("Extracted %s items from the queue, queue has %s items \
            left" % (len(result), current_size))
            # END DEBUG CODE

            return result
```

But for some reason it doesn't work.

Observe the following shell session:

```
>>> import multiprocessing
>>> q = multiprocessing.Queue()
>>> for i in range(100):
...     q.put([range(200) for j in range(100)])
... 
>>> q.qsize()
100
>>> l=dump_queue(q)
Queue has 100 items initially.
Dumping complete:
0 items were added to the queue.
Extracted 1 items from the queue, queue has 99 items left
>>> l=dump_queue(q)
Queue has 99 items initially.
Dumping complete:
0 items were added to the queue.
Extracted 3 items from the queue, queue has 96 items left
>>> l=dump_queue(q)
Queue has 96 items initially.
Dumping complete:
0 items were added to the queue.
Extracted 1 items from the queue, queue has 95 items left
>>>
```

What's happening here? Why aren't all the items being dumped?

Answer (score 30):

Try this:

```
import Queue
import time

def dump_queue(queue):
    """
    Empties all pending items in a queue and returns them in a list.
    """
    result = []

    for i in iter(queue.get, 'STOP'):
        result.append(i)
    time.sleep(.1)
    return result

import multiprocessing
q = multiprocessing.Queue()
for i in range(100):
    q.put([range(200) for j in range(100)])
q.put('STOP')
l=dump_queue(q)
print len(l)
```

Multiprocessing queues have an internal buffer which has a feeder thread which pulls work off a buffer and flushes it to the pipe. If not all of the objects have been flushed, I could see a case where Empty is raised prematurely. Using a sentinel to indicate the end of the queue is safe (and reliable). Also, using the iter(get, sentinel) idiom is just better than relying on Empty.

I don't like that it could raise empty due to flushing timing (I added the time.sleep(.1) to allow a context switch to the feeder thread, you may not need it, it works without it - it's a habit to release the GIL).

Comment: Good general idea Jesse, but even safer and more reliable would be to use as sentinel a `uuid` string (or for threading rather than multiprocessing, a specific `sentinel=object()), rather than a generic string. Even then you could get trouble if some other thread is getting at the same time; the only really _safe_ way is the one relying on Queue's internals, alas!-)

Comment: You're right. I went for the 'quick' solution using a string sentinel, but that only works in this particular case. I'm beginning to wonder if mp.queue need some sentinel support built into the Queue's

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I had a similar problem today which this response helped me to solve. Full problem write-up: http://www.bryceboe.com/2011/01/28/the-python-multiprocessing-queue-and-large-objects/

Answer (score 3):

```
# in theory:
def dump_queue(q):
    q.put(None)
    return list(iter(q.get, None))

# in practice this might be more resilient:
def dump_queue(q):
    q.put(None)
    return list(iter(lambda : q.get(timeout=0.00001), None))

# but neither case handles all the ways things can break
# for that you need 'managers' and 'futures' ... see Commentary
```

I prefer `None` for sentinels, but I would tend to agree with jnoller that mp.queue could use a safe and simple sentinel. His comments on risks of getting empty raised early is also valid, see below.

**Commentary:**

This is old and Python has changed, but, this does come up has a hit if you're having issues with lists <-> queue in MP Python. So, let's look a little deeper:

First off, this is not a bug, it's a feature: https://bugs.python.org/issue20147. To save you some time from reading that discussion and more details in [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html), here are some highlights (kind of philosophical but I think it might help some who are starting with MP/MT in Python):

- MP Queues are structures capable of being communicated with from different threads, different processes on the same system, and in fact can be [different (networked) computers](https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2012/01/24/distributed-computing-in-python-with-multiprocessing)
- In general with parallel/distributed systems, *strict synchronization* is expensive, so *every time* you use part of the API for any MP/MT datastructures, you need to look at the documentation to see what it promises to do, or not. Hint: if a function doesn't include the word "lock" or "semaphore" or "barrier" etc, then it will be some mixture of "asynchronous" and "best effort" (approximate), or what you might call "flaky."
- Specific to this situation: Python is an interpreted language, with a famous single interpreter thread with it's famous "Global Interpreter Lock" (GIL). If your entire program is single-process, single threaded, then everything is hunky dory. If not (and with MP it's egregiously not), you need to give the interpreter some breathing room. *time.sleep()* is your friend. In this case, timeouts.

In your solution you are *only* using flaky functions - get() and qsize(). And the code is in fact worse than you might think - dial up the size of the queue and the size of the objects and you're likely to break things:

[image]

Now, you can work with flaky routines, but you need to give them room to maneuver.  In your example you're just hammering that queue. All you need to do is change the line `thing = queue.get(block=False)` to instead be `thing = queue.get(block=True,timeout=0.00001)` and you should be fine.

The time 0.00001 is chosen carefully (10^-5), it's about the smallest that you can safely make it (this is where art meets science).

Some comments on why you need the timout: this relates to the internals of how MP queues work. When you 'put' something into an MP queue, it's not actually put into the queue, it's queued up to *eventually* be there. That's why `qsize()` happens to give you a correct result - that part of the code knows there's a pile of things "in" the queue. You just need to realize that an object "in" the queue is not the same thing as "i can now read it."  Think of MP queues as sending a letter with USPS or FedEx - you might have a receipt and a tracking number showing that "it's in the mail," but the recipient can't open it yet. Now, to be even more specific, in your case you get '0' items accessible right away. That's because the single interpreter thread you're running hasn't had any chance to process stuff that's "queued up", so your first loop just queues up a bunch of stuff for the queue, but you're immediately forcing your single thread to try to do a get() before it's even had a chance to line up even a single object for you.

One might argue that it slows code down to have these timeouts. Not really - MP queues are heavy-weight constructs, you should only be using them to pass pretty heavy-weight "things" around, either big chunks of data, or at least complex computation. the act of adding 10^-5 seconds actually does is give the interpreter a chance to do thread scheduling - at which point it will see your backed-up `put()` operations.

### Caveat

The above is not completely correct, and this is (arguably) an issue with the design of the get() function. The semantics of setting timeout to non-zero is that the get() function will *not* block for longer than that before returning Empty. But it might not actually be Empty (yet). So if you know your queue has a bunch of stuff to get, then the second solution above works better, or even with a longer timeout. Personally I think they should have kept the timeout=0 behavior, but had some actual built-in tolerance of 1e-5, because a lot of people will get confused about what can happen around gets and puts to MP constructs.

In your example code, you're not actually spinning up parallel processes. If we were to do that, then you'd start getting some random results - sometimes only some of the queue objects will be removed, sometimes it will hang, sometimes it will crash, sometimes more than one thing will happen. In the below example, one process crashes and the other hangs:

[image]

The underlying problem is that when you insert the sentinel, you need to know that the queue is finished. That should be done has part of the logic around the queue - if for example you have a classical master-worker design, then the master would need to push a sentinel (end) when the last task has been added. Otherwise you end up with race conditions.

The "correct" (resilient) approach is to involve [managers](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#managers) and [futures](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html):

```
import multiprocessing
import concurrent.futures

def fill_queue(q):
    for i in range(5000):
        q.put([range(200) for j in range(100)])

def dump_queue(q):
    q.put(None)
    return list(iter(q.get, None))

with multiprocessing.Manager() as manager:
    q = manager.Queue()
    with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
        executor.submit(fill_queue, q)  # add stuff
        executor.submit(fill_queue, q)  # add more stuff
        executor.submit(fill_queue, q)  # ... and more
        
    # 'step out' of the executor
    l = dump_queue(q)

# 'step out' of the manager
print(f"Saw {len(l)} items")
```

Let the manager handle your MP constructs (queues, dictionaries, etc), and within that let the futures handle your processes (and within that, if you want, let another future handle threads). This assures that things are cleaned up as you 'unravel' the work.