# Checking for empty Queue in python's multiprocessing

Tags: python, queue, multiprocessing

I have a program using python's packages multiprocessing and Queue. One of my functions have this structure:

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue
def foo(queue):
   while True:
       try:
           a = queue.get(block = False)
           doAndPrintStuff(a)
       except:
           print "the end"
           break

   if __name__ == "__main__"
     nthreads = 4
     queue = Queue.Queue()
     # put stuff in the queue here 
     for stuff in moreStuff:
         queue.put(stuff)
     procs = [Process(target = foo, args = (queue,)) for i in xrange(nthreads)]
     for p in procs:
       p.start()
     for p in procs:
       p.join()
```

the idea is that when I try to extract from the queue and it is empty, it'll raise an exception and terminate the loop. So I have two questions:

1) is this a safe idiom? Are there better ways to do this?

2) I tried to find what is the exact exception that is raised when I try to `.get()` from an empty queue. Currently my program is catching all exceptions, which sucks when the error is somewhere else and I only get a "the end" message.

I tried:

```
  import Queue
  queue = Queue.Queue()
  [queue.put(x) for x in xrange(10)]
  try: 
       print queue.get(block = False)
  except Queue.Empty:
       print "end"
       break
```

but I got the error as if I hadn't caught the exception. What's the correct exception to catch?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The exception should be `Queue.Empty`. But are you sure you got the *same* error? In your second example, you also switched the queue itself from `multiprocessing.Queue` to `Queue.Queue`, which I think may be the problem.

It might seem strange, but you have to use the `multiprocessing.Queue` class, but use the `Queue.Empty` exception (which you have to import yourself from the `Queue` module)

Answer (score 2):

It appears that the Queue is empty until the put buffers are flushed, which may take a while.

The solution to our problem is [to use](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1541117/819417) [sentinels](http://www.bryceboe.com/2011/01/28/the-python-multiprocessing-queue-and-large-objects/), or maybe the built-in [task_done()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.JoinableQueue.task_done) call:

> task_done()
>
> Indicate that a formerly enqueued task is complete. Used by queue consumer threads. For each get() used to fetch a task, a subsequent
>   call to task_done() tells the queue that the processing on the task is
>   complete.
>
> If a join() is currently blocking, it will resume when all items have been processed (meaning that a task_done() call was received for
>   every item that had been put() into the queue).
>
> Raises a ValueError if called more times than there were items placed in the queue.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example- As @Steven said above, you need to use the queue.Empty exception from the standard queue. The note from documentation (https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html):

> Note
>
> multiprocessing uses the usual queue.Empty and queue.Full exceptions
> to signal a timeout. They are not available in the multiprocessing
> namespace so you need to import them from queue.

basic example:

```
 from multiprocessing import Process, Queue, Manager
 import queue

def firstPass(q):
    driver = getDriver()

    while True:
        try:      
            link = q.get_nowait()   
            f(driver, link)
        except queue.Empty:
            logger.info("empty queue")
            driver.close()
            break
```

Answer (score -4):

Try reading the [queue](http://docs.python.org/library/queue.html) library docs.  Aren't you looking for [Queue.empty()](http://docs.python.org/library/queue.html#Queue.Queue.empty)?